# How to add pyflakes, bottle, hypothesis to a PyCharm project?

Tags: python, pycharm, bottle, python-hypothesis

How to add testing frameworks and Web frameworks to a PyCharm project.
***How to add pyflakes, bottle, hypothesis to a PyCharm project?***

To install, the above mentioned frameworks and any other, follow the below link.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

The solution given is from the following answer, Answer 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is setting a proper python environment for development. You can use the virtualenv / pipenv /conda and install the mentioned packages. Please follow the following links.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Then you will be able to install all the packages you want following the instructions in the below link.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: The question is "How to install the mentioned packages?".PyCharm with the creation of the project also creates a virtualenv environment. In fact, a PyCharm project is created within a virtualenv environment.

Comment: The third link gives you a step by step instruction to install packages into the project interpreter.